# Installing OS X On A Hard Drive Partition With Windows On Primary On Legacy BIOS

Tags: macos, hard-drive, windows-8.1, bios

I Wish To Install OS X On My Hard Disk.

It Already Has Windows 8.1 Installed On The Primary Partition.
So I Shrinked My Hard Disk, Got 150GB Extra And Want To Install OS X On It.

The Thing Is, I Want To Keep My Windows And Install OS X On The New Partition.

Many People Have Said That I Need To Wipe My Hard Disk Completely To Install OS X For Legacy BIOS.

So, Is This True Any Why ?
Also, Is There Any Possible Way Around This ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of OSX on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Answer (score -1):

OSX is (U)EFI only - this means, that you either need a compatible implementation (i.e. buy a Mac) or use a software implementation, that itself is started from legacy BIOS mode (i.e. Clover or Chamaeleon).

Your Windos installation is set up for a BIOS system, not an EFI system, so you are in a situation, where you can start **either** the one **or** the other.

In addition to that, the partition table for a BIOS Windows install needs to be MBR, which doesn't allow OSX to boot.

The only known (to me) workaround is to use two harddrives, with Clover or friends on one and Windows on the other, then boot from one of them via the BIOS boot menu.